# Replacing app.config at runtime

Tags: c#, app-config

Here is my appconfig:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="cn" connectionString="User ID=YOUR_USER_HERE; Password=YOUR_PASS_HERE;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=.)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=.)));"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have tried this function:

```
public void updateConfigFile(string con)
        {


            //updating config file
            XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            //Loading the Config file
            XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
            foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
                {
                    {
                        xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[1].Value = con;
                    }
                }
            }
            //writing the connection string in config file
            XmlDoc.Save("App.config");            
        }
```

That did not work. It ran without any error. But it did not save connectionString into appconfig file. I also tried this idea:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["Blah"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=blah;Initial Catalog=blah;UID=blah;password=blah";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

I get an error that says UnauthorizedAccess. ( I believe it is because of my school network)

These two options have not worked so far. I also tried to set `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"]` to my custom connectionString. Since it is readonly, that failed too. Is there any other idea that I can replace connectionString at runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run as administrator.

Comment: I added app.manifest and changed the attribute. That did not work either.

Comment: Wrong file name, not app.config, it will resemble foobar.exe.config for the foobar program.  Note that you already know the path of the file, you loaded its xml.  So use the exact same path when you save it.

Comment: I cannot thank  you enough. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the app configuration file must be done before your application starts, as certain keys are read by the runtime when your application is being bootstrapped only, and others are turned into readonly.

You can dynamically change the configuration entries of the `AppSettings` section only by referencing the `System.Configuration` assembly. All the other keys are by design read only.

If you don't want to alter the configuration before starting the application, you need to think about all the involved entities: who is going to read your connection string? If it is you, you can simply store it somewhere else or even in the `AppSettings` key. Instead, if external components require to read it from your configuration file, you have no chance that changing the architecture of your application in order to have a wrapper that does the changes before running your application.

The `AppSettings` key ca be changed in this way, after refencing the `System.Configuration` **assembly** (this is vital).

*App.config*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="key1" value="configuration"/>
    </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

*Program.cs*

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"] = "changed";

            var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];

            Console.WriteLine($"This is the new key: {value}.");
        }
    }
}
```